# syntax error at or near "ORDER" in hibernate

Tags: sql, postgresql, hibernate, persistence

I have an query that I want to execute via persistence.query in hibernate.

```
final String StatusQuery = convertStringFiltersToQuery(StatusFilters);

 sql = String.format("Select * FROM Program p LEFT JOIN p.user vt LEFT JOIN vt.Vendor LEFT JOIN p.Program WHERE vt.Status IN (%s) ORDER BY ID DESC",
                StatusQuery);

entityManager.createNativeQuery(sql).getResultList();
```

But When I try to execute it, I got error like

> Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: syntax error at
> or near "ORDER"

Anything I am missing here ?

Thanks in Advance !!

**Updated** the question after got the suggestion from below answer:

Now have changed the query but seems the same issue happened:

```
 sql = String.format("Select * FROM Program p LEFT JOIN p.user vt LEFT JOIN vt.Vendor LEFT JOIN p.Program on (p.program_id = p.UserProgram.program_id) WHERE vt.Status IN (%s) ORDER BY ID DESC",
```

Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: syntax error at or near "ORDER"

Comment: Try `DESC` instead of `DSC`.

Comment: sorry, typo while raising the question.

Comment: I don't know hibernate but I am accustomed to seeing ON clause in SQL queries joining tables.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you'll need a condition to [join](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/tutorial-join.html) . These `syntax errors at or near 'x'` is usually pointing to an error just before `x`, in this case, the LEFT JOIN has no ON clause.

Edit: Response to question update, you'll need conditions for each `LEFT JOIN` clause, here's an [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8779918/postgres-multiple-joins), and [here](https://learnsql.com/blog/how-to-left-join-multiple-tables/).

Comment: Have updated the question, no luck:(

Comment: Refer to edit, The query needs some more work.